# SQL query returns empty values

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I wrote the following query. In SQL developer I get the expected result, but when I    running it from C# code (in Visual Studio) I'm getting an empty value.

`V_GVTR` is a **view** in my Oracle database schema

```
TRDATE is DATE  
TRTIME is VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
```

sample from view:

```
    TRDATE | TRTIME  
2018.01.01 | 12:22:27
```

The Query:

```
String query_tr = "select tr_id from V_GVTR where to_date(trdate || trtime, 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') between to_date('2018.06.28 00:00:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('2018.06.30 00:00:00', 'YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS')"    
OracleDataAdapter da_tr = new OracleDataAdapter(query_tr, Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
DataTable dt_tr = new DataTable();
da_tr.Fill(dt_tr);
```

Comment: maybe YYYY-MM-DD has to become YYYY.MM.DD

Comment: I can't help you on the c# side, but your query is doing far more date/string conversions that is necessary. If you're working with dates, then use dates; don't bother with strings! I.e. in your case, do the conversion of your strings into dates and leave it there, so that you're comparing dates with dates, rather than strings with strings. That means your query ends up like `select tr_id from V_GVTR where to_date(trdate || trtime, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') between to_date('2018-06-28 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') and to_date('2018-06-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

Comment: I am assuming here that your trdate and trtime parameters have the extra space between them; if not, then you'd need to change it to be `trdate || ' ' || trtime`

Comment: Where are `GVDATE` and `GVTIME` used? (They've just appeared in your last comment but I'm not sure how that relates to the question.) In your question, isn't `to_char(to_date('2018-06-28 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` just a verbose way of writing `'2018-06-28 00:00:00'`?

Comment: I have removed wrong queries, and I have corrected my query in my original post. Yes, I'm running this query in the same database. And both query is exactly the same (C# and SQL Developer)

Comment: I would suggest modifying the view (or creating a new view) which provides the full date and time in a single `DATE` column. Seriously, you run into situations like this when you build a clause around a date-time that is split into multiple columns and the time is provided as a string.

Comment: There is a difference between returning empty (null) values and not returning any values. The second case seems more likely here.

Comment: Sorry, yes, not returning any values.

Comment: Are there entries in the TRTIME column that have nulls in them?  May be worth having a coalesce in there